# How can I rewrite predefined messages for the WelcomePage in different languages in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, message

I have 3 languages and I need to change the `AppName` according to the language I've chosen.
I wrote this:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName={code:GetMyAppName}

[Code] 
function GetMyAppName(param : String) : String;
begin
  case ActiveLanguage of
    'en': Result := 'AB Office Client';
    'ru': Result := 'Клиент АБ Офис';
    'ua': Result := 'Клієнт АБ Офіс';
  end;   
end;
```

And here I have my language-dependent `[Messages]` section:

```
[Messages]
en.WelcomeLabel1=Welcome to [APPNAME] Setup program. This program will install [APPNAME] on your computer.
ru.WelcomeLabel1=Вас приветствует программа установки [APPNAME] Эта программа установит [APPNAME] на Ваш компьютер.
ua.WelcomeLabel1=Вас вітає програма встановлення [APPNAME]. Ця програма встановить [APPNAME] на Ваш комп'ютер.
```

My question is: how can I transfer the result of the function `GetMyAppName` to the `[APPNAME]`? I could have done that by inserting a previously defined constant like `{#AppName}`, but I cannot use functions from the `[Code]` section with preprocessor's directives.
The same question is when I use `[CustomeMessages]` instead. Like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName={cm:AppName}

[CustomMessages]
en.AppName=AB Office Client
ru.AppName=Клиент АБ Офис
ua.AppName=Клієнт АБ Офіс
```

Also, I know that there are some arguments `%1` and `%2` in `[Messages]` section, but i have no idea how to use them. For me `%1` and `%2` argument just won't transfer to the `AppName` and `AppVersion` accordingly. They just stay as `%1` and `%2`.
And finally, changing the `.isl` file manually is not an option for me.
Would really appreciate your help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defaults are:

```
WelcomeLabel1=Welcome to the [name] Setup Wizard
WelcomeLabel2=This will install [name/ver] on your computer.%n%nIt is recommended that you close all other applications before continuing.
```

So just follow that – Use `[name]` and `[name/ver]` placeholders in your translations.

---

If you need other customization, see [Can I use .isl files for the messages with preprocessor directives in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64932221/850848) or [Full preprocessor support in Inno Setup language files (isl)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64967700/850848).