# Full preprocessor support in Inno Setup language files (isl)

Tags: inno-setup

I use three languages with my installer and at the moment I'm doing all the overrides inside my script. Here's an example:

```
[Messages]
en.SetupWindowTitle=Setup - %1 {#AppVersion}
ru.SetupWindowTitle=Установка - %1 {#AppVersion}
ua.SetupWindowTitle=Встановлення - %1 {#AppVersion}
en.SetupAppRunningError=Setup has detected that {#SetupSetting('VersionInfoOriginalFileName')} is currently running.%n%nPlease close all instances of it now, then click OK to continue, or Cancel to exit.
ru.SetupAppRunningError=Обнаружен запущенный экземпляр {#SetupSetting('VersionInfoOriginalFileName')}.%n%nПожалуйста, закройте все экземпляры приложения, затем нажмите «OK», чтобы продолжить, или «Отмена», чтобы выйти.
ua.SetupAppRunningError=Виявлено запущений екземпляр {#SetupSetting('VersionInfoOriginalFileName')}.%n%nБудь ласка, закрийте всі копії програми та натисніть «OK» для продовження, або «Скасувати» для виходу.
[CustomMessages]
en.AppRunningError=Setup has detected that {#AppExeName} is currently running.%n%nPlease, close the {#AppExeName} application, then click «OK» to continue or «Cancel» to exit. 
ru.AppRunningError=В памяти находится {#AppExeName}.%n%nЗавершите работу {#AppExeName} и нажмите «OK», чтобы продолжить, или «Отмена», чтобы выйти. 
ua.AppRunningError=В пам'яті знаходиться {#AppExeName}.%n%nЗавершіть роботу {#AppExeName} та натисніть «OK» для продовження, або «Скасувати» для виходу.
```

I have lots of messages overridden inside the script. I would like to know what is the most effective way to transfer all those overrides into the `.isl` files taking into account that I have preprocessor directives `{#...}` used. I could use `FmtMessage(...)`, but that means that I would have to include `FmtMessage(...)` for every single message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check, if some of the less invasive solutions might not cover your needs:
[Can I use .isl files for the messages with preprocessor directives in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64932221/850848)

---

If you want a full preprocessor support in .isl files, you can pass them through the actual Inno Setup preprocessor:

- Factor out common include file (`defines.iss`) with all the variable definitions (and some support code):

  ```
  // Definitions
  #define AppVersion "1.2.3"
  // more definitions ...

  // Support code
  #define PreprocessedTranslationFile GetEnv("TEMP") + "\lang.isl"
  #define SavePreprocessedTranslation() SaveToFile(PreprocessedTranslationFile)
  ```
- Include that file at the beginning of your .iss and all your .isl's:

  ```
  #include "defines.iss"
  ```
- Call `SavePreprocessedTranslation` at the end of all your .isl's:

  ```
  #expr SavePreprocessedTranslation()
  ```
- Make the preprocessor call `iscc` on the modified .isl files. It will of course fail, as the .isl is not a valid .iss, but the preprocessor part of `iscc` should complete and create the preprocessed .isl file.

  ```
  #define DebugPreprocessLanguage 0

  #define PreprocessLanguage(Path) \
    Local[0] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6\ISCC.exe", \
    DeleteFileNow(PreprocessedTranslationFile), \
    Local[1] = DebugPreprocessLanguage ? SourcePath + "\islpreprocess.log" : "nul", \
    Local[2] = "/C """"" + Local[0] + """ """ + Path + """ " + \
               ">> " + Local[1] + " 2>&1 """, \
    Exec("cmd", Local[2], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
    (FileExists(PreprocessedTranslationFile) || \
      Error(Path + " failed to preprocess")), \
    Local[3] = GetEnv("TEMP") + "\" + ExtractFileName(Path), \
    CopyFile(PreprocessedTranslationFile, Local[3]), \
    DeleteFileNow(PreprocessedTranslationFile), \
    Local[3]
  ```
- And use the preprocessed .isl files in the `[Languages]` section.

  ```
  [Languages]
  Name: "en"; MessagesFile: {#PreprocessLanguage("Default.isl")}
  Name: "nl"; MessagesFile: {#PreprocessLanguage("Dutch.isl")}
  ```

If you have problems, set `DebugPreprocessLanguage` to `1` to see the .isl preprocessor output.

You can even improve the process by making the preprocessor add the `#include "defines.iss"` and `#expr SavePreprocessedTranslation()` automatically to the .isl's before calling the `iscc`.

Comment: If I specify the full path to the `.isl` files like this: `{#PreprocessLanguage("<fullpath>\Default.isl")}` the compiler spits out the error: _Error executing macro PreprocessLanguage <fullpath>\Default.isl failed to preprocess._ Can't I specify the full path like this? I need it because my language files are not in the same folder as the script file.

Comment: @JConstantine So what did you do to to debug the problem? Did you set the `DebugPreprocessLanguage` to 1 and did you check the `islpreprocess.log`? I guess the problem is that the `defines.iss` cannot be found.

Comment: I did set the `DebugPreprocessLanguage` to 1 and what I have in the `islpreprocess.log` is just some jibberish: `ЌҐўҐа­® § ¤ ­® Ё¬п Ї ЇЄЁ.`.

Comment: @JConstantine You might be opening the file in a wrong encoding.

Comment: I've just opened it with Notepad++. It says _Invalid folder name_ in Russian for some reason. The path I'm passing to the `#PreprocessLanguage` is `C:\ABOfficeProjects\Install\InnoSetupProject\Languages\English.isl`. The path is correct and the file does exist there.

Comment: What do you get if you replace `Local[0] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6\ISCC.exe"` with `Local[0] = "dir"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225617/discussion-between-jconstantine-and-martin-prikryl).