# Can I use Inno Setup preprocessor to decide inside the isl file which messages refer to which installer?

Tags: inno-setup, preprocessor, isl

I have four installers built with separate .iss files: client installer,  server installer, client update installer, server update installer. At the moment I use separate `isl` files for each installer.

My question is can I use Inno Setup preprocessor inside the `isl` file to decide which messages refer to which installer so I could use only one instance of `isl` file for each language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a preprocessor in .isl files, only if you use a hack like this one from your previous question: [Full preprocessor support in Inno Setup language files (isl)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64967700/850848)

When you do, you can use [`/D` switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc) on the commandline of the `iscc` process that preprocesses the .isl files (in the `PreprocessLanguage` macro). Use the variable to identify your build. And you can then use the variable in your .isl files any way you like. You already know how: [How can I pass command line parameters with a value to the Inno Setup Compiler, so I can use them in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60888905/850848)